# Biblatex Printing "ibid" Lowercase at Beginning of Footnote

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

My ›house‹ citation style is an author-year system with the citations placed in foot- or endnotes rather than in the text. I'm using biblatex's `\autocite` exclusively, with `autocite=footnote` so I don't have to care about placing my citation commands in the right place, and to facilitate switching from my style to an inline citation style when I have to submit a text of mine to someone who demands inline citations. (That's because \autocite can be placed before or after terminal punctuation, and will move the footnote mark or brackets to the correct position later.)

Once in a while, though, I have to add a longer comment of mine to a citation. The `postnote` IMHO isn't a proper place for that, especially when further citations are needed within that comment. So I'm going for a `\footnote{\cite{...}...}` construction. This works fine most of the time, the only minor annoyance being I now have two different citation commands (but that's for another thread).

But when the citation starting that footnote is a duplicate of the previous one, the resulting `ibid` will be printed in *lowercase,* in contrast to the ones that result from the `\autocite`s. It's as if biblatex isn't aware of the position of that citation, thinking it's somewhere in the middle rather than at the beginning of that footnote. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}    
testing.\autocite{malinowski}
testing\autocite{malinowski}.
testing.\footnote{\cite{malinowski}. I'd like to add: \lipsum[1]} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\Cite{malinowski}` with a capital "C" at the start of sentences. Or `\bibsentence\cite{malinowski}`, but why would you do that?

Comment: well, I do know *that* one `:)` My impression is that biblatex, usually, is smart enough to take care of things like that on its own, so I what I'm trying to arrive at is a solution that makes use of biblatex's usual smartness ...which of course doesn't exclude fundamental changes to what I'm doing here. My whole `\footnote{\cite{}}` construction might be a bad idea altogether -- if that's the case, please let me know.

Comment: Ahhh, no I do not think `biblatex` is smart enough to track these things. It cannot tell the start of sentences without `\bibsentence` or similar commands (the fact that it is able to track punctuation and capitalisation *within* the bibliography is because it inserts these commands itself), it would also not be able to properly capitalise "ibid" in `\cite{foo}. \cite{foo}`.

Comment: You could probably define a new command for those long postnotes that implicitly calls `\bibsentence` and be done with the thing.

Comment: yup, I was thinking in that direction too, based on your previous comments. [My original hope was that if biblatex is able to automatically use `Ibid` vs. `ibid` (which it is!), it'll be able to do that in this special case as well, if provided with some help.] So, unless someone comes up with something entirely different, that's a decent workaround I guess.

Comment: Well, have a look at my edited answer, I defined a new command that might come close to what you want (it uses `\Cite`, but does so automatically).

Comment: works pretty well, will give it some further testing... thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that question, just wanted to ask the same one. My solution was to search&replace \footnote{\cite with \footnote{\Cite or could anything go wrong with that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the start of sentences you should probably use `\Cite`, which is defined (in `biblatex.def`) as

```
\newrobustcmd*{\Cite}{\bibsentence\cite}
```

It therefore capitalises the first word it prints (as long as `biblatex` is able to capitalise that word).

MWE

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,DIV=7,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}    
testing.\autocite{malinowski}
testing\autocite{malinowski}.
testing.\footnote{\Cite{malinowski}. I'd like to add: \lipsum[1]} % Prob 2
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For your purpose you might want to define a new command (we use LaTeX3's `xparse` here, so load `\usepackage{xparse}`)

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\longnoteffotcite}{o o m +m}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\footnote{\Cite[#1]{#3}. {#4}}}
     {\footnote{\Cite[#1][#2]{#3}. {#4}}}}
```

That behaves like `\footcite` but takes a mandatory long (i.e. allows for `\par`s and stuff) additional postnote.

The standard `postnotes` in `biblatex` do not seem to allow for `\par`s.

MWE

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,DIV=7,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\longnoteffotcite}{o o m +m}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\footnote{\Cite[#1]{#3}. {#4}}}
     {\footnote{\Cite[#1][#2]{#3}. {#4}}}}

\begin{document}    
testing.\autocite{malinowski}
testing\autocite{malinowski}.
testing.\longnoteffotcite[9]{malinowski}{I'd like to add: \lipsum[1-2]\par Hi}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very late response, but most academic style guides require "ibid." to *always* be lower case even if at the start of a sentence. So biblatex is doing the right thing by default.

Comment: Mhhh, normally `biblatex` would capitalise "ibid" at the beginning of a sentence, it is just that in this particular instance, `biblatex` can't tell that we are at the beginning of a sentence.