# Repeated in-footnote citation call-outs: Problem with Capitalisation

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, capitalization

When I put `\cite{}` within two consecutive footnotes, the second footnote begins with a lowercase letter instead of with a capital.

So the problem is here:

[image]

Just like in the third footnote "Ebd." should begin with the capital letter "E"

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{grillmeier1989,
    Address = {Freiburg/{\,}Basel/{\,}Wien},
    Author = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dq1.175 2/3},
    Date-Added = {2014-07-24 15:28:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 08:50:39 +0000},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Publisher = {Herder},
    Title = {Jesus der Christus im Glauben der Kirche},
    Volume = {2: Die Kirche von Konstantinopel im 6. Jahrhundert},
    Year = {1989}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{Here comes some text: \cite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1989}}
\blindtext\footnote{\cite[][S. 56]{grillmeier1989}}
\blindtext\footcite[][S. 56]{grillmeier1989}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: The `\bibliography{\jobname}` instruction is deprecated. Use `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` instead.

Comment: The problem occurs when you write `\footnote{\cite...}`, but not when you write `\footcite...`. Just out of curiosity: Is there a reason for not using `\footcite`?

Comment: You should use `\footcite` whenever possible. If you for some reason can not use `\footcite`, but must call `\cite` at the beginning of a `\footnote`, you should use `\Cite` (with a capital "C") instead. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171572/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258212/35864

Comment: Thank you Moewe!  That solved it. Can you post it as an answer please so that I can accept it? @Mico, yes there is: Inside footnote I have \index commands and some other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've had two similar questions before [Biblatex Printing "ibid" Lowercase at Beginning of Footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171572/35864) and [How to ensure the first letter of a footnote is always uppercase?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258212/35864), since in these two questions the advice was only implicit let it make me explicit here.

You should if at all possible use `\footcite{sigfridsson}` instead of `\footnote{\cite{sigfrdisson}}`.

There are legitimate reasons why one would not want to use `\footcite`, though. Especially if a lot of text follows the citation, it might feel wrong to put all of that into the postnote.
In that case you should use

```
\footnote{\Cite{sigfridsson} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
```

This is a general rule. If you start a new sentence with a citation command, use the capitalised form (`\Cite` instead of `\cite`, `\Textcite` instead of `\textcite`, ...). While `biblatex` can keep track of capitalisation in text it has produced itself, it is much harder to keep track of capitalisation and sentence structure in the text around citations that `biblatex` has no influence on. So you need to help `biblatex` along by telling it that you are at the beginning of a sentence. The difference between `\Cite` and `\cite` rarely surfaces, so it can be easy to forget about that.

If you always want to see the "S." for page numbers, you should change the `postnote` field format accordingly. Then you can drop the "S." in the postnote. You also do not need the empty prenote argument, `biblatex` already knows you want a postnote. Have a look at my changes to your example `.bib` entry as well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{grillmeier1989,
    Address = {Freiburg and Basel and Wien},
    Author = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dq1.175 2/3},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Publisher = {Herder},
    mainTitle = {Jesus der Christus im Glauben der Kirche},
    Volume = {2},
    title = {Die Kirche von Konstantinopel im 6. Jahrhundert},
    Year = {1989}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{Here comes some text: \cite[See][56]{grillmeier1989}}
\blindtext\footnote{\Cite[56]{grillmeier1989}}
\blindtext\footcite[56]{grillmeier1989}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding "S." I am aware of the possibility to change postnote field format. But the thing is I don't always need an "S.". Sometimes its "Col." and sometimes something completely different. Thanks though!

Comment: @eklisiarh `biblatex` can do that for you as well, you just need to tell it about that. Have a look at the `pagination` and `bookpagination` fields.